How to set the option `top' in tcb only in first breakable part in PikaChu tcolorbox?
I came across the cute pikachu tcolorbox at here, then I modified it a bit(add color to it and make it breakable),however I confronted that the option top=60pt couldn't be applied only in Middle and Last part in a tcolorbox, where should I place the option top=60pt for the normal apperence of the Middle and Last breakable box?
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{ctexart}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\tcbset{
        pikachu/.style={
            enhanced,breakable,%
            colback=yellow!60,
            colframe=black,boxrule=0.6mm,
            enlarge top by=7.0mm,
            enlarge bottom by=2.0mm,
            top=60pt,sharp corners=south,arc=14mm,
        overlay unbroken and first={
            \begin{scope}[shift={([xshift=9.0mm,yshift=-13mm]frame.north west)},rotate=30]
            \path[draw=black,fill=black,line width=0.5mm] (0,0) arc (0:360:2mm);
            %第二处改色
            \path[fill=yellow!60] (-.05,.08) arc (0:360:1mm);
            \path[draw=black,fill=black,line width=0.5mm] (1.2,0) arc (0:360:2mm);
            %第三处改色
            \path[fill=yellow!60] (1.1-.05,.08) arc (0:360:1mm);
            \path[draw=black,fill=black] (0.4,-.15) circle [x radius=0.06,y radius=0.03] (0:360);
            \path[draw=black,line width=0.4mm,xshift=0.5mm,yshift=-3.5mm] (0,-.02) .. controls (.1,-.1) and (.15,-.14) .. (.35,0)
            .. controls (-.15+.7,-.14) and (-.1+.7,-.1) .. (0+.7,-.02);
            %第四处改色
            \path[draw=black,fill=red!75,line width=0.4mm] (1.6,-0.4) arc (0:360:2mm);
            \path[draw=black,fill=red!75,line width=0.4mm] (-.28,-.5) arc (0:360:2mm);
            \end{scope}
        },
        underlay unbroken and first={
            \begin{scope}[shift={([xshift=0mm,yshift=0mm]frame.north west)}]
                %第五处改色
            \path[draw=yellow!60,line width=0.7mm] (1.51,-0.03)--(2.55,-0.03);
            \path[draw=yellow!60,line width=2.0mm] (0.1,-0.84)--(0.1,-2);
            \end{scope}
        },
        underlay unbroken and first={
            \begin{scope}[shift={([xshift=0mm,yshift=0mm]frame.north west)}]
            \path[draw=black,fill=yellow!60,line width=0.6mm,rounded corners=1.0pt] (1.5,-0.03) .. controls (2.5,0.3) and (3.5,-0.5) .. (3.7,-0.6) .. controls (2.7,-0.5) and (2.5,-0.5) .. (2.2,-0.4);
            \clip (1.5,-0.03) .. controls (2.5,0.3) and (3.5,-0.5) .. (3.7,-0.6) .. controls (2.7,-0.5) and (2.5,-0.5) .. (2.2,-0.4);
            \fill[black] (2.4,-0.5) to [out=10,in=210] (3.4,-0.3) -- (4,-0.7) -- cycle;
            \end{scope}
        },
        underlay unbroken and first={
            \begin{scope}[shift={([xshift=9.06mm,yshift=4.93mm]frame.north west)},rotate=60]
            \path[xscale=-1,draw=black,fill=yellow!60,line width=0.6mm,rounded corners=1.0pt] (1.5,-0.03) .. controls (2.5,0.3) and (3.5,-0.5) .. (3.7,-0.6) .. controls (2.7,-0.5) and (2.5,-0.5) .. (2.2,-0.4);

            \clip[xscale=-1] (1.5,-0.03) .. controls (2.5,0.3) and (3.5,-0.5) .. (3.7,-0.6) .. controls (2.7,-0.5) and (2.5,-0.5) .. (2.2,-0.4);

            \fill[xscale=-1,black] (2.4,-0.5) to [out=10,in=210] (3.4,-0.3) -- (4,-0.7) -- cycle;
            \end{scope}
        },
        underlay unbroken and first={
            \begin{scope}[xscale=1.1,yscale=0.4,shift={([xshift=-5mm,yshift=-19mm]frame.north east)},rotate=38]
            % [xscale=1,yscale=1,shift={([xshift=-8mm,yshift=-50mm]frame.north east)},rotate=0]
            % \draw [help lines] (-6,0) grid (6,6);
            \path[draw=black,fill=yellow!60,line width=0.6mm,rounded corners=1.0pt]
                (0,0) -- (0.3,0) -- (0.7,1.2) -- (-0.5,1.4) -- (-0.1,2.7) -- (-1.8,3) to [out=80,in=245] (-1,5.4) -- (-3.9,6) to [out=245,in=90] (-4.6,2.2) -- (-2,2) -- (-2.2,1.1) -- (0.2,0.7) -- cycle;
            \clip (0,0) -- (0.3,0) -- (0.7,1.2) -- (-0.5,1.4) -- (-0.1,2.7) -- (-2,3) to [out=80,in=245] (-1.2,5.4) -- (-4.1,6) to [out=245,in=90] (-4.8,2.2) -- (-2.2,2) -- (-2.5,1.1) -- (0.2,0.7) -- cycle;
            \fill (-0.8,0.7) -- (-0.2,0.9) -- (-0.5,1.1) -- (-0.2,1.1) -- (-0.4,1.2) -- (-0.1,1.25) -- (-0.4,1.45) -- (1,1.5) -- (1,0) -- (-0.5,0) -- cycle;
            \end{scope}
        },
        underlay first={
            \begin{scope}[shift={(frame.north west)},rounded corners=10pt]
            \path[fill=black,xshift=36mm,yshift=0mm] (0,0) -- (0.3,-0.8) -- (0.35,0);
            \path[fill=black,xshift=42mm,yshift=0mm] (0,0) -- (0.3,-0.8) -- (0.35,0);
            \end{scope}
        },
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{tcolorbox}[pikachu]
    \textbf{问题}\quad 在平面直角坐标系中．等腰Rt$\triangle$OAB的斜边OA在x轴上．P为线段OB上-动点（不与O，B重合）．过P点向x轴作垂线．垂足为C．以PC为边在PC的右侧作正方形PCDM。
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \lipsum[2-4]
    \begin{tcolorbox}[pikachu]
        \lipsum[1-3]
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \lipsum[2-3]
    \begin{tcolorbox}[pikachu]
    \lipsum[3-8]
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}


Another Bouns Question is that:
is there possible to set the title option in a proper location of the pikachu-box?(what I mean is that with the overlay now, is there exists location to place the title without destroy the lovely pikachu?) If add the title will make it unlovable, I will give up to add the title. PikaChu~

You could use pad at break for setting the pad after the break and create an attached title to position where you like:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{ctexart}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\tcbset{
        pikachu/.style={
            enhanced,breakable,%
            colback=yellow!60,
            colframe=black,boxrule=0.6mm,
            enlarge top by=7.0mm,
            enlarge bottom by=2.0mm,
            top=60pt,
            pad at break=8pt,
            sharp corners=south,
            arc=14mm,
            title={#1},
            attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-60pt},
            coltitle=black,
            fonttitle=\bfseries,
            boxed title style={colback=yellow!60, colframe=yellow!60},
        overlay unbroken and first={
            \begin{scope}[shift={([xshift=9.0mm,yshift=-13mm]frame.north west)},rotate=30]
            \path[draw=black,fill=black,line width=0.5mm] (0,0) arc (0:360:2mm);
            %第二处改色
            \path[fill=yellow!60] (-.05,.08) arc (0:360:1mm);
            \path[draw=black,fill=black,line width=0.5mm] (1.2,0) arc (0:360:2mm);
            %第三处改色
            \path[fill=yellow!60] (1.1-.05,.08) arc (0:360:1mm);
            \path[draw=black,fill=black] (0.4,-.15) circle [x radius=0.06,y radius=0.03] (0:360);
            \path[draw=black,line width=0.4mm,xshift=0.5mm,yshift=-3.5mm] (0,-.02) .. controls (.1,-.1) and (.15,-.14) .. (.35,0)
            .. controls (-.15+.7,-.14) and (-.1+.7,-.1) .. (0+.7,-.02);
            %第四处改色
            \path[draw=black,fill=red!75,line width=0.4mm] (1.6,-0.4) arc (0:360:2mm);
            \path[draw=black,fill=red!75,line width=0.4mm] (-.28,-.5) arc (0:360:2mm);
            \end{scope}
        },
        underlay unbroken and first={
            \begin{scope}[shift={([xshift=0mm,yshift=0mm]frame.north west)}]
                %第五处改色
            \path[draw=yellow!60,line width=0.7mm] (1.51,-0.03)--(2.55,-0.03);
            \path[draw=yellow!60,line width=2.0mm] (0.1,-0.84)--(0.1,-2);
            \end{scope}
        },
        underlay unbroken and first={
            \begin{scope}[shift={([xshift=0mm,yshift=0mm]frame.north west)}]
            \path[draw=black,fill=yellow!60,line width=0.6mm,rounded corners=1.0pt] (1.5,-0.03) .. controls (2.5,0.3) and (3.5,-0.5) .. (3.7,-0.6) .. controls (2.7,-0.5) and (2.5,-0.5) .. (2.2,-0.4);
            \clip (1.5,-0.03) .. controls (2.5,0.3) and (3.5,-0.5) .. (3.7,-0.6) .. controls (2.7,-0.5) and (2.5,-0.5) .. (2.2,-0.4);
            \fill[black] (2.4,-0.5) to [out=10,in=210] (3.4,-0.3) -- (4,-0.7) -- cycle;
            \end{scope}
        },
        underlay unbroken and first={
            \begin{scope}[shift={([xshift=9.06mm,yshift=4.93mm]frame.north west)},rotate=60]
            \path[xscale=-1,draw=black,fill=yellow!60,line width=0.6mm,rounded corners=1.0pt] (1.5,-0.03) .. controls (2.5,0.3) and (3.5,-0.5) .. (3.7,-0.6) .. controls (2.7,-0.5) and (2.5,-0.5) .. (2.2,-0.4);

            \clip[xscale=-1] (1.5,-0.03) .. controls (2.5,0.3) and (3.5,-0.5) .. (3.7,-0.6) .. controls (2.7,-0.5) and (2.5,-0.5) .. (2.2,-0.4);

            \fill[xscale=-1,black] (2.4,-0.5) to [out=10,in=210] (3.4,-0.3) -- (4,-0.7) -- cycle;
            \end{scope}
        },
        underlay unbroken and first={
            \begin{scope}[xscale=1.1,yscale=0.4,shift={([xshift=-5mm,yshift=-19mm]frame.north east)},rotate=38]
            % [xscale=1,yscale=1,shift={([xshift=-8mm,yshift=-50mm]frame.north east)},rotate=0]
            % \draw [help lines] (-6,0) grid (6,6);
            \path[draw=black,fill=yellow!60,line width=0.6mm,rounded corners=1.0pt]
                (0,0) -- (0.3,0) -- (0.7,1.2) -- (-0.5,1.4) -- (-0.1,2.7) -- (-1.8,3) to [out=80,in=245] (-1,5.4) -- (-3.9,6) to [out=245,in=90] (-4.6,2.2) -- (-2,2) -- (-2.2,1.1) -- (0.2,0.7) -- cycle;
            \clip (0,0) -- (0.3,0) -- (0.7,1.2) -- (-0.5,1.4) -- (-0.1,2.7) -- (-2,3) to [out=80,in=245] (-1.2,5.4) -- (-4.1,6) to [out=245,in=90] (-4.8,2.2) -- (-2.2,2) -- (-2.5,1.1) -- (0.2,0.7) -- cycle;
            \fill (-0.8,0.7) -- (-0.2,0.9) -- (-0.5,1.1) -- (-0.2,1.1) -- (-0.4,1.2) -- (-0.1,1.25) -- (-0.4,1.45) -- (1,1.5) -- (1,0) -- (-0.5,0) -- cycle;
            \end{scope}
        },
        underlay first={
            \begin{scope}[shift={(frame.north west)},rounded corners=10pt]
            \path[fill=black,xshift=36mm,yshift=0mm] (0,0) -- (0.3,-0.8) -- (0.35,0);
            \path[fill=black,xshift=42mm,yshift=0mm] (0,0) -- (0.3,-0.8) -- (0.35,0);
            \end{scope}
        },
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{tcolorbox}[pikachu={First Title}]
    \textbf{问题}\quad 在平面直角坐标系中．等腰Rt$\triangle$OAB的斜边OA在x轴上．P为线段OB上-动点（不与O，B重合）．过P点向x轴作垂线．垂足为C．以PC为边在PC的右侧作正方形PCDM。
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \lipsum[2-4]
    \begin{tcolorbox}[pikachu={Second Title}]
        \lipsum[1-3]
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \lipsum[2-3]
    \begin{tcolorbox}[pikachu={Third Title}]
    \lipsum[3-8]
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[pikachu]
      PikaChu box with no title. 
      PikaChu box with no title. 
      PikaChu box with no title. 
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}





Thanks for your brilliant solution, I learn more about the pad at break option.

After Zoom Out I found some small bug of th PikaChu~ At the upper left corner there exists a little outer yellow block, and the line conjunction is a little sharp. For the first one, I modified the fill region, and for the second one, with the option line cap=round can fix it!

@Explorer Yes, I see it, but that small bug is present in your MWE, too. It doesn't depend on the options I added.

it's because I didn't aspect the tcb detailedly, sorry!

@Explorer No problem :D
